# How do I get the Block Header Size in Oracle?

Tags: oracle10g

I'm trying to calculate the size of a few tables as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/497214/), but I can't find the block header size variable

How do I get it? Is it some kind of formula?

I'm using Oracle 10g

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This site has a good discussion on the format of the block header: http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/ora/concepts/db_block.html.  Basically the block header = fixed header + transaction header + table directory + row directory.  Here are the individual pieces:

fixed header = 57 bytes

transaction header = between 23*inittrans and 23*maxtrans

table directory = 4*number of tables (usually 1 unless you're using clusters)

row directory = 2*stored rows

In short while you can come up with a rough estimate, it's not a fixed size for each data block.

Comment: Those "=" chars, I assume they're meant to be "+" chars, yes?

Comment: Okay, looks like that's what the Q'er was after, +1.

Answer (score 0):

[This page](http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/ora/concepts/db_block.html) (for 10g) says it's 57 bytes.

Comment: I saw that, but I think it's just one part of the "whole block header"

Comment: The block header size is 57 bytes, did you mean the block size?

Comment: Or the actual overhead which is discussed on that page as well (block header, transaction header, table directory, ...)?